# Div saving its color after refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Basically its a div that changes the color after clicking on it.

I would like to make the div save its color after refreshing the page - I don't think cookies are good idea because it will save the color on user pc.

*I need to make it the same color for everyone visiting the site*.

Here's the code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>change</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .color {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        background: black;
        margin: auto auto;
      }
      .clicked {
        background-color: red;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="color" id="change" onclick="changeColor();"></div>

    <script>
      $('.color').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
      });
    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Where do i start?

Comment: set a cookie with that  color code on click and read it after page load 

Comment: Cookies! Or DOM storage

Comment: See this reference for information on cookies http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: i dont think cookies are good idea because it will save the color on user pc. I need to make it the same color for everyone visiting the site

Comment: @spleen, if you don't want to store it locally, then store it in database

Comment: @spleen : For that you'll need to send the value of the color to the server , store the value in some database and retrieve the value of the color from the database when anyone requests that page .

Comment: @spleen I've put together a simple example using a JSON file as a database - so my answer below should serve you well enough. Depending on how deep you want to go, and how synchronised you want the state of the box to be, I would also suggest looking into using `Node.js` with `sockets.io` - this allows for real time updates between the server and the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Very simple JSON Database Example**

I have written some code that will enable you to save the state of the background color in a JSON file, which you would store on your server.

Essentially, the JSON file functions as a simple database (you probably shouldn't implement it this way, but it's simple enough for a beginner to understand) which centralizes the data, allowing all the users to see the box in the same state.

This is how you could achieve this:

**index.js**:

```
$.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/4zzaa", function(data){
    if (data.clicked) {
        $("#box").addClass("clicked");
    }
    $("#box").addClass("loaded");
})
.fail(function(){
    //Handle JSON fetch error
});

$('#box').click(function(){
    var isClicked = $(this).hasClass("clicked") ? false : true;
    var str = JSON.stringify({clicked: isClicked});
    $.ajax({
        url:"https://api.myjson.com/bins/4zzaa",
        type:"PUT",
        data: str,
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            $("#box").toggleClass("clicked");
        }
    })
    .fail(function(){
        //Handle PUT error
    });
});
```

**https://api.myjson.com/bins/4zzaa**:

```
{
    "clicked": "true"
}
```

I seriously suggest doing some reading on [`jquery.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) and [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). These will be a good starting point for you.

[Here's my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/omgtoblerone/b08o24vv/2/) - note that you will have to replace the URLs in the `getJSON` and `ajax` methods when you use it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is awesome, works perfectly, i dont know how to thank you! :)

Comment: Glad I could help :) upvote and accept the answer and thats all the thanks I need!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Before refresh:

```
var color = "value";
localStorage.setItem("color", color);
```

After refresh:

```
var color = localStorage.getItem("color");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this either by setting cookies or localstorage.
I have implemented the functionality using localstorage.
Try it in your code it will work

```
    $(function(){
        if(localStorage.getItem("divClicked")){
             $('.color').addClass('clicked');
        }
      else{
      localStorage.setItem("divClicked",false);
      }
    });

    $('.color').click(function(){
      localStorage.setItem("divClicked", !localStorage.getItem("divClicked"));
      $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    });
```

Comment: Read the comments on the answer - unfortunately, the poster is looking for a *decentralized* persistent solution

Comment: I hope the poster just demand to save the state of the div per user whether is clicked or not. And the solution I provided is fulfilling the need

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer, it works GREAT but unfortunately i will need to save the info in database i think, the div needs to be same color for every user.

Answer (score 0):

Its better if you use the id instead of .color. Here is a solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>change</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .color {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        background: black;
        margin: auto auto;
      }
      .clicked {
      width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: red;
        margin: auto auto;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="color" id="change" onclick="changeColor();"></div>

    <script>
      function changeColor(){
        $('#change').toggleClass('clicked');
        $('#change').toggleClass('color');
        if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
            localStorage.setItem("color", $('#change').attr('class'));
        }
      }

      $(document).ready(function(){

    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined" && localStorage.getItem("color") !='') {
        $('#change').attr('class','');
        $('#change').attr('class', localStorage.getItem("color"));
    }
    });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should save data on the server, for example in database or file